# absolute positioning css with height 100% element?

Tags: jquery, css

I have elements positioned absolutely on a page, but within those elements I will have dynamic content nested. If the content grows, my elements outside are absolute positioned so they don't move and obstruct the content.

Is there any tricks around this?

Can I get jquery to add some pixels to 'top' of my positioned elements offsetting the #ContainerDiv?

Comment: will you provide any snapshot or create [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to batter understand  the problem.

Comment: Below answer accepted, thanks for your time @punit. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off I don't suggest using Javascript to fix a layout bug, unless it's with dynamic content anyway.

Now, what kind of a layout are you trying to go for? If you're trying to do 100% height columns there are various layout tutorials on how to achieve this purely with CSS (and often with a repeating background for the column). You can find them simply by [searching for 100% height](https://www.google.com/search?q=100%25%20height). What you're going to end up doing is hacking your CSS for different browsers to get them to act like they support `min-height: 100%;`